# Regular expresission to split line

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

I need regular expression to split following text

```
es7600: indv_nr, ksl_dato, se_nr, cvr_nr, annul_kod, projekt_kod, virk_start_dto, virk_oph_dto, abon_status_kod, virk_kod, virk_type_txt
```

I need to capture the text before colon and after colon

```
var = regex # result es7600
var1 = indv_nr, ksl_dato, se_nr, cvr_nr, annul_kod, projekt_kod......
```

I guess the question is, how to grab everything before the : and everything after the colon

In this case i need the clean regex as NIFI extractText does not support expressionlanguage

Comment: And what have you tried to achieve the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i assume you have `es7600: indv_nr, ksl_dato, .....` as a flowfile content

then you can use `ExtractText` processor with adding new dynamic parameter:

`MyKey` with value `([^:]+):(.*)`

also you may set to `true` `Enable DOTALL Mode` and `Enable Multiline Mode`

after execution if content matches the regexp above you should have new attributes in your flow file:

`MyKey.1` will contain the value before `:`

`MyKey.2` will contain the value after `:`

Comment: Thank you that did it for me

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're after?

`([^:]+): *([^$]+)`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/yE2tjb/1)

Group1 captures everything before the colon
Group2 captures everything after the colon (and zero or more space chars)